# EXC_BAD_ACCESS boundingRectWithSize

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, exc-bad-access

When I deploy my app on an iPhone 5 with iOS 7.0.6 I always receive `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on call `boundingRectWithSize` from a string object, although on iPhone 5s with iOS 7.1.2 everything works fine.

Did someone have similar problem with iOS 7.0.6? Maybe someone can recommend me an alternative for this method.

My code:

```
NSString *string = self.stringLabel.text;      
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(200, 300);
CGRect stringRect = [string boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize
                                                 options:(NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading|NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin)
                                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.stringLabel.font}
                                                 context:NULL];
```

Comment: Łukasz are you sure I think you shoudn't avoid using "string" as a variable name. This might be a keyword. I found an issue related to this method over here:
https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/issues/217

Comment: Do you mean to replace string var with self.stringLabel.text (direct call)? It should not make any difference, I set up only reference to self.stringLabel.text, so it still should works, and it works wall but only on iOS 7.1.2, I doesn't understand why it does not on iOS 7.0.6.

Comment: I have no idea what cause your problem. If i were you I would try to reproduce this issue and then call `po self.stringLabel.text` and `po self.stringLabel.font` in lldb console to check if all variables are not nil. If not I would enable `NSZombie` to receive a pointer to deallocated instance and then investigate which variable is deallocated.

Comment: @db42 No, to me it is a bug in iOS.

Comment: Confirmed bug for iOS `7.0.2/4/6`